# Let $X \sim\operatorname{unif} (1,2)$. Find the distribution of $ Y=X+2/X $

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

If $ X $ follows the uniform distribution in $ (1,2) $ what is the distribution of $ Y= X + \frac{2}{X} $ ?
I thought that $ P( X + 2/X <=y )$ => $ P(X^2-2xy +2 <=0)$ , where y is at

$(2\sqrt{2},3 ) $ . Then i found the roots of $ X^2-2Xy +2 =0 $ let them be ρ1,ρ2 where $ρ_2\geρ_1$ so the probability that i want $P(ρ_2\ge X \ge ρ_1)$  but i coudn't find that because i can't show when $ρ_1$ is at $ (1,2) $ .  I think $ρ_2 $ is always at $(1,2)$ . Is there any easier eay to think this? Because i get confused.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a hint -- you have to make sure $y$ takes on appropriate values (what is its range?).

$P(Y \leq y) = P(X+ 2/X \leq y) = P(X^2 + 2 \leq yX) = P(X^2 - yX + 2 \leq 0)$.

Now, $f(x) = x^2 -  y x + 2$ is a parabola that opens up with roots $\frac{y \pm \sqrt{ y^2 - 8}}{2}$, so the set of $x$ such that $f(x) \leq 0$ is given by the interval between the roots. 
So, $$ P(X^2 - yX + 2 \leq 0) = P \left( \frac{y - \sqrt{ y^2 - 8}}{2} \leq X \leq \frac{y + \sqrt{ y^2 - 8}}{2}\right).$$

Now, note that $P(a \leq X \leq b) = F(b) - F(a)$ where $F(x) = \begin{cases} 0 & x < 1 \\ x-1 & 1 \leq x \leq 2 \\ 1 & x >2 \end{cases}$.

Comment: thank you for your answer! i thought the same  but i wasnt sure if the roots of $ x^2-2yx+2$ , for some y at$ (2\sqrt{2} ,3) $ ,was at $(1,2)$ , i think ρ2 ,where ρ2 is the biggest root is always at (1,2) but ρ1 where ρ1<ρ2 isn't at (1,2) for every y at (2$\sqrt{2}$ ,3) . So for some y  the probability i want i think is P(1<X<ρ2) . Is all that correct? I took (2$\sqrt{2}$ ,3) because there $fy(y)$ > 0 ,where $fy$ is the density of $ Y $